# A Particular Symmetric Bilinear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Does there exist symmetric bilinear map on $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that

> $$<v, v> \neq 0 \quad \forall v \in \mathbb{C}^n-\{0\}?$$

Comment: $v \mapsto f(u,v)$ is linear hence $f(u,0) = 0$. now if you meant bi-affine, then yes take $f(v,v) = \langle u,v \rangle + i$ with $\langle .,.\rangle$ the canonical inner product : $f(v,v) = \|v\|^2 + i \ne 0$

Answer (score 2):

Nope. E.g. bilinearity means linearity in the first argument and thus:
$$
\langle 0, 0 \rangle
= \langle 0\cdot 0, 0 \rangle
= 0 \langle 0, 0 \rangle
= 0
$$
and $0 \in \mathbb{C^n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Nop, because if $f$ is a bilinear function, then $f(0, 0) = 0$

Comment: Ops, sorry :( I will edit

Comment: sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1):

No, because $\langle 0 , 0 \rangle \not=0$ would prevent the map from being both bilinear and well-defined. In other words, such a map would be multi-valued.

$$\langle v , v \rangle = \langle v + 0 , v +0 \rangle = \langle v , v+0 \rangle + \langle 0, v+ 0 \rangle = \langle v , v \rangle + \langle v, 0 \rangle + \langle 0, v \rangle + \langle 0, 0 \rangle \\ = \langle v, v \rangle + \langle0, 0\rangle + 2\langle v, 0 \rangle \not= \langle v , v \rangle$$

as long as $2 \langle v, 0 \rangle \not= \langle 0, 0 \rangle$ for some $v$ (which must be the case, take for example $v$=0; if $\langle 0,0 \rangle \not=0$, then 2$\langle 0,0\rangle \not= \langle 0, 0 \rangle$).

A similar argument also applies in the case of conjugate symmetry:

$$\langle v, v \rangle + \langle 0,0\rangle + 2Re[\langle v, 0 \rangle]$$ with the term $2Re[\langle v, 0 \rangle]$ not possibly equalling $\langle 0, 0 \rangle$ for all $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

The basic idea of the proof is that a linear map needs to "inherit" some of the properties of a field, namely needs inherit the additive identity (i.e. such that $f(a+b) = f(a)$ always for the unique $b$ such that $a+b=a$ always -- particularly we must have $f(0)=0$ -- relaxing this restriction gives us in general an affine function but not a linear one), and the condition imposed prevents this from being possible.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out the trivial problem that the zero vector is a problem, and we should also point out that if $n=1$ and the zero vector is exempted, the naive dot product is such a bilinear form. But furthermore the answer is negative if the zero vector is exempted and $n>1$.

If $\langle v,v \rangle\neq 0$ for all nonzero $v$, then clearly the bilinear form must be nondegenerate. Then in some basis the symmetric bilinear form diagonalizes to the naive dot product. In case $n=2$ you can see that $(1,i)$ is a null vector, and by padding with zeros you can get a null vector in any $n> 2$.

Comment: I didn't get your point. Can you explain a little bit. I have exempted zero vector.(I had forgot that before).

Comment: @Sushil I've explained why there is never a symmetric bilinear form over C  for n> 1 which is nonzero on V\0. What part is unclear?

Comment: First of all which one is there for n=1? What you mean by Naive dot product

Comment: @Sushil "naive dot product" means that after fixing the basis, the dot product using coordinate vectors $x,y$ is $x^\top y$.  If $n=1$ the dot product of the vector $(x_0)$ with the vector $(y_0)$ is just $x_0y_0$. Since $\Bbb C$ is a domain, $x_0x_0\neq 0$ if $x_0\neq 0$. But for dimension $2$ or more, you can always produce a null vector for the naive dot product.

Answer (score 1):

There is no polynomial function of the complex coordinates of $v \in C^n$ ($n>1$) for which $f(v)=0$ implies $v=0$.

One polynomial equation cannot cut out a locus of codimension higher than than $1$.